Binomial coefficient relation for rational powers
In Eckle's book "Models of Quantum Matter" he gives the exercise to show that the two expressions (7.14)

and (7.230)

are the same (note $w_1 = (u_1,v_1),\, w_2 = (u_2, v_2)$). Could anyone help me show this? I have written $\cosh$ and $\cos$ in terms of exponentials and tried using the binomial formula. However, I can't see how to get this in terms of just two sums.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.
